# Weird duplicate window behaviour in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

I use TeXShop on a Mac and keep updated with the latest version, which is currently 3.98. Sometimes when I open TeXShop, with windows from the previous session, one of the files opens twice and minimises to the dock. I am wondering if this has anything to do with the fact that the files are on Dropbox and there might be some syncing issue. Has this happened to anyone else?

Computer

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1212)

MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2012)

2 GHz Intel Core i7 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

[image]

Comment: This is the normal behaviour if the two files are linked using the `% !TEX root = ...` directives. If you open a file with a `% !TEX root =` line, then the root file will also open and be minimized to the dock.  Perhaps this is what's happening?

Comment: I'm saying that the same file opens twice. In particular, it's the root file that opens twice.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote TeXShop. I suspect that Alan Munn's answer is correct. In TeXShop Preferences under the Misc tab, in the section "Project Root File", you can turn off this minimizing behavior.

If this is not the problem, then I need more details; perhaps a copy of the file which opens twice and a screenshot.

Dick Koch

Comment: I've added my computer details and a screen shot. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the recent files facility. I had turned this off in System Preferences yesterday and the problem seemed to go away. What happened in the screenshot occurred when launching TeXShop immediately after just now turning it back on.